# await not working inside nested for...of loop -- typeorm - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, typeorm, for-of-loop

I am trying get some data and add those to an existing dataset (object), but the data shows empty. However, I am able to get the data from database using `typeorm` query.

I realised my mistake that the method returns the data before my loop gets completely iterated. Found that `for...of` loops work better for `async/await`. But still no luck.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
export const getTopicDetails = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {
  try {
    let topicDetail: any = await Chapter.createQueryBuilder("topic")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("topic.grs", "grs")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("grs.srs", "srs")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("grs.points", "grs_points")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("srs.points", "srs_points")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("grs_points.srs", "grs_points_srs")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("grs_points.points", "grs_points_points")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("srs_points.points", "srs_points_points")
      .where("topic.id = :id", { id: req.params.id })
      .andWhere("grs.sequence IS NULL")
      .andWhere("srs.parent_sr_id IS NULL")
      .orderBy("grs.id", "ASC")
      .addOrderBy("grs_points.sequence", "ASC")
      .getOne();

    for (const gr of topicDetail.grs) {
      for (const point of gr.points) {
        for (const firstLevelPoint of point.points) {
          var srs = await Srmodule.createQueryBuilder("srs")
            .where("srs.grId = :grId", { grId: firstLevelPoint.id })
            .getMany();

          // this is returning an empty object
          nestedProperty.set(topicDetail, `2`, srs);
          
          // this thing returns as expected
          nestedProperty.set(topicDetail, `3`, [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "srNo": "1.01.02.01",
                "grId": 7,
                "title": "test",
                "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                "created_at": "2021-06-21",
                "addedBy": 1,
            }
        ]);
        }
      }
    }

    if (topicDetail) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: true,
        data: topicDetail,
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({ status: false, error: "No data found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ status: false, error: error });
  }
};
```

This is what I get in response:

```json
"status": true,
    "data": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": {},
        "3": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "srNo": "1.01.02.01",
                "grId": 7,
                "title": "test",
                "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                "created_at": "2021-06-21",
                "addedBy": 1,
            }
        ]
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have came up with a workaround. I was having too much problems with such nested tree entities. So I decided to put all my entires in a single database table and add parent child relation. So that I can pull them with query, but idk why the query returns incomplete data. So again I used a function to build an nested object with the raw array I'm getting from query. Here's a sample: https://gist.github.com/subhamchbty/6dd2367d06906bde988b2834692cded6

Answer (score 1):

"await" can only be used inside an async function!

```js
async function getData() {
  const data = await doSomeAsyncWork();
  console.log(data)
}

function doSomeAsyncWork() {
  return Promise.resolve("data");
}

getData();
```

So wrap all your for loop inside an async function!

Comment: all those are already inside a `async` function. I have updated the complete code, please have a look.

Comment: @SubhamChakraborty So what's the problem you are facing after updating the code??

Comment: still getting an empty object

Comment: Sorry about that. Try breaking the problem into smaller pieces instead of doing all at once. Use the debugger see what's going wrong.This is not a problem that I can reproduce because I don't have access to your database!